# my installed app does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I'm having an Issue when I install My C# winform App in C:\ProgramFiles everytime I try to Run it, I get the usual "App has stopped working" error with the 3 options, Close, Debug, check for online solutions.

Now I'm Pretty sure that I got all my Dlls and Requirements in the InstDir. I'm Sure of this cuz If I copy/paste the InstDir to another location, say desktop for example, The App works !!

how to solve this ???

error looks like this

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01: typingfreak.exe
Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03: 5029e51b
Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
Problem Signature 05: 4.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06: 4ba1da6f
Problem Signature 07: 3dab
Problem Signature 08: 13c
Problem Signature 09: System.UnauthorizedAccess
OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
Locale ID:    12297
Additional Information 1: 0a9e
Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3: 0a9e
Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Please, Any Help

Answer (score 4):

Your application is raising `System.UnauthorizedAccess`.  Given the description of what's happening when you copy and paste to another folder, my guess is that it's trying to write data into the local folder.

If you're installing into `Program Files`, this won't be allowed (unless you run it as administrator), since that isn't writable by your user.

Answer (score 3):

Try to run it as an administrator - if it works - your app is probablly accessnig some area in the system that the user is not permitted to access - (usually a directory). check your file accessing methods

Comment: how to make program to installed in any directory and work perfectly

Comment: well,In windows 7 there were lots of security changes for apps, it is not longer free and hackable like previous versions,so an app cant just be installed anywhere and have full access to anything. are you accessing the filesystem from your application(opening/saving files)?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the line of your error:

```
Problem Signature 09: System.UnauthorizedAccess
```

I'd speculate that you're either running from a directory that you do not have the proper permissions needed for the application or that you copied the application from a network location (or the web) and did not mark it as safe.

After verifying the Windows permissions for the directory, I'd recommend that you right-click the executable, select properties, and look for a button labeled "Unblock" on the dialog.  Click it.  You may or may not need to repeat for the DLLs.

Comment: how to make program to installed in any directory and work perfectly

Comment: I would recommend creating a setup package to do the work, rather than just dropping your files into Program Files manually.  For more detail, see:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353

Comment: is this problem has relation with Sign Application and Deployment Manifests and like stuffs

Comment: There wasn't enough information provided to tell, honestly.  I suspect it is a more mundane cause such as file system permissions or network download blocking.

Comment: i created a program which was written in c# and uses SQL server 2008 express database then i created setup package with installShield 2010 priemer ed. i installed the app on a computer everything works fine setup creates database in computer and program will be installed in C:/ hard drive when i open program it will give the ERROR PLEASE any HELP

Comment: ... and does that SQL Express database live in the same directory as the application?   If so, that is a likely cause of your permissions error.  That database should not live in the Program Files directory, as it is a protected directory that a non-administrator will not have rights to.  Your database file would be better served in a sub directory of either %AppData% or %AllUsersProfile%, depending on whether it is restricted to a specific user of the machine or available for all.

Comment: actually i put DB in Windows folder for security reason maybe its silly but where to put it?? can you suggest me a directory because its first time i do sth like that and want to put in somewhere secure

Comment: With due respect, that is the worst possible place to put it.  As I mentioned in my previous comment, if your application is to be used by all on a machine, I'd go with "%AllUsersProfile%\MyAppName"  If it is to be used by only a single user, I'd go with "%AppData%\MyAppName".  Both of those locations are low-security profile locations intended for data and similar types of files.